# Welcome screen for Arab countries

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, marketing

On their website, my company wants to welcome visitors from Arab countries with some kind of "intro page" specifically tailored to comfort Arab visitors.

Currently, we are thinking about a welcome text and maybe a welcome picture that both integrate nicely with our corporate design.

Is there anything we should try to avoid when dealing with Arab visitors?

Can anyone recommend specific tips or strategies towards welcome pages in general and Arab visitors in particular?

Comment: This is to be appreciated as a good question in a broader sense. However, the specific point you asked seems to be not about UX but a cultural issue. It is not even specifically relevant to a web site alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say use the Hijri format which would be appreciated by the Muslims in the Arab countries; there are many sites that offer APIs for that.

Avoid excess skin if you have pictures of people.

Everything needs to be aligned right to left with the text. Actually don't just swap an English intro page to an Arabic one. Put some effort into it; it'll feel more genuine and it would be more appreciated.

I'm trying to help some more here, but given the fact that I have no idea what industry you're in, I'm a bit bound.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the existence of suitable APIs, that can be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Arabian web users are no different than other users from other cultures,

when it come to text, simple and clear sentences are preferred bearing in mind the differences in the spoken accent between regions

while for images, Arabian features for places or ppl are mostly preferred

dont try to translate text to arabic by an automatic translator, it wont be accurate